# YAML with erb is not parsing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, yaml, erb

Why this yaml file won't parse?

```
---
<% sensor_types = YAML.load_file('db/seed-fixtures/sensor_type.yml') %>
<% sensor_types.each do |sensor_type| %>
sensor<%= sensor_type['id'] %>:
  id: <%= sensor_type['id'] %>
  title: <%= sensor_type['title'] %>
  unit: "<%= sensor_type['unit'] %>"
  valid_min: <%= sensor_type['valid_min'] %>
  valid_max: <%= sensor_type['valid_max'] %>
  codename: <%= sensor_type['codename'] %>
  scale_base_ten_exponent: <%= sensor_type['scale_base_ten_exponent'] %>
<% end %>
```

this file is used for fixtures in my tests, it is loaded by rspec from the fixtures directory.

when I try it I get: "mapping values are not allowed in this context at line 4 column 28 (Psych::SyntaxError)"

Comment: How do you load this file? Do you use it as a generic yaml file or do you load it as an ERB file and then parse it as yaml?

Comment: I edited the question to answer your question, I think Rspec load it as yaml.

Comment: Can you provide a test yaml file with that error line? Also, did you try to load with the syck gem yet instead of Psych? gem install syck, then require 'yaml', then require 'syck', and then YAML::ENGINE.yamler = 'syck' and then you load the yaml file

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You can't load a YAML file containing ERB like a basic YAML file. Checkout this [post](https://web.archive.org/web/20160406205220/https://urgetopunt.com/rails/2009/09/12/yaml-config-with-erb.html).

What you can do instead is (in a spec initializer or a before hook):

```
FIXTURE_CONFIG = YAML.load(ERB.new(File.read("#{Rails.root}/path_to_your_file.yml.erb")).result)
```

And then use this variable in  your test.

Comment: I'm using this YAML file for fixtures so it's actually does the ERB rendering as stated in the post you linked. but your code helped me debug the file and figure that the problem was with the source yaml I was loading. thanks.

Comment: the original post referenced in the first line of this answer is a dead link. I wonder what it was linking too. I'm looking to learn some more about how Rails, YAML and ERB are interacting. Specifically, I have some ERB in `database.yml` and I'm curious how Rails is parsing this, but looks like other YAML files would need special parsing to embed ruby code...

Comment: @J.R.BobDobbs indeed -- I updated the link to use wayback machine's save. As for the `database.yml` it's a special case in Rails: it uses the `Rails::Application::Configuration` class which is going to parse the yaml as you can see here: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails/Application/Configuration.html#method-i-database_configuration

Which is going to call `ActiveSupport::ConfigurationFile.parse` (that does the ERB interpolation).