# Rails 5: How do I reference I18n translations from another yaml config file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-i18n

I have a config file:

```
# config/meta.yml
base_meta:
  title: 'Top 10 Cats'
```

It has an corresponding initializer:

```rb
# config/initializers/meta.rb
META = YAML.load_file("#{Rails.root.to_s}/config/meta.yml")
```

I can access the title like so:

```rb
META['base_meta']['title'] #=> "Top 10 Cats"
```

However, I want to internationalize my meta data. I believe this should be handled by the existing `locales/` yaml files.

How do I reference the existing translation?

```
# config/locales/en.yml
en:
  title: 'Top 10 Cats'
```

I've tried using erb, but it doesn't work:

```
# config/meta.yml
base_meta:
  title: t(:title)
```

Renaming the file to `config/meta.yml.erb` has no effect either.

Is there a way to reference the I18n keys from my config file?

Comment: Maybe you could use an [alias node](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2786196) to reference a previously defined anchor. Or parse the file manually via erb, see [YAML with erb is not parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25115384/477037).

Comment: BTW, let's say you have multiple locales, e.g. `locales/en.yml` and `locales/de.yml`. Would you expect `META['base_meta']['title']` to return the value of the currently selected locale or a static value, e.g. the `en` one?

Comment: It should return the value specific to the current locale.

Comment: In that case, erb is not an option – it would insert the value for the app's default locale. Neither is a YAML alias because it isn't locale aware. What about inserting the I18n key in your YAML file, i.e. `title: title`, and retrieving its value via `t(META['base_meta']['title'])` at runtime?

Comment: Yes, this sounds like a better approach.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of its value, you could add the *key* for the existing translation in your YAML file:

```
# config/locales/en.yml
en:
  cats:
    title: 'Top 10 Cats'

# config/locales/de.yml
de:
  cats:
    title: 'Top 10 Katzen'

# config/meta.yml
base_meta:
  title: 'cats.title'
```

So it just returns that key:

```
META['base_meta']['title'] #=> "cats.title"
```

Which can then be passed to `I18n.t`:

```
I18n.locale = :en

t(META['base_meta']['title']) #=> "Top 10 Cats"

I18n.locale = :de

t(META['base_meta']['title']) #=> "Top 10 Katzen"
```

Answer (score -1):

Try replace in application.rb default value of *config.i18n.load_path* parameter with that:

```
config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('config/locales/**/*.yml').to_s]
```

It works for me.

Comment: The problem is not loading the file but referencing I18n values within the file.

Comment: Restart the application.

Comment: Read the question again, that isn't the problem either.